# python, skype4py

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-11.04, skype4py

```
$ sudo python2.6
>>> import Skype4Py
>>> skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
>>> skype.Attach()
```

And nothing happens.. just it turn me out to the console.
And I'm trying next to get result without *sudo*

```
$ python2.6
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Mar 25 2011, 19:24:58) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Skype4Py
>>> skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
>>> skype.Attach()
$ Segmentation fault
```

I don't understand - it's wrong result.

I want to get invite from skype to approve access for my application, which is I take in win32 application. But there is no result. How i can get it?

You can find Skype4Py lib here - http://sourceforge.net/projects/skype4py/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some say that this is a bug because Skype4Py is configured for other systems. Try using with X11:

```
import Skype4Py
skype = Skype4Py.Skype(Transport='x11')
skype.Attach()
```

Comment: It's a decision - a lot of Thanks :)